# Turn 2 linq expressions into

Tags: linq

Is there anyway to change the following 2 linq expressions into 1?

```
var criticalCategories =
    _commonDao.GetAllByExpression<CategoryItem>(
        x => x.Category.Uid == gridAnswer.ActivityCategory.Uid && x.Critical);

if(criticalCategories.Any())
{
    criticalWeight = criticalCategories.Min(x => x.Weight);
}
```

Comment: Are you looking to combine `criticalCategories.Any` and `criticalCategories.Min`? What should the value of `criticalWeight` be when `criticalCategories` is empty?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Enumerable.DefaultIfEmpty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355419.aspx) to make sure that `Min` will produce a specific value if your source sequence contains no elements.

You could then write:

```
var criticalCategories = _commonDao.GetAllByExpression<CategoryItem>(...);

criticalWeight = criticalCategories
                     .Select(x => x.Weight)
                     .DefaultIfEmpty(42)
                     .Min();
```

The above is trivially chainable, but I did not actually chain it here because I 'm not quite sure how `criticalCategories` is supposed to be used later on (if at all). Could you please clarify?